# I get error when displaying the data in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

Below is the code which executes at last when displaying the data into listview! 
But when i provide code like

> myViewHolder.route.setText(" Hello there");

it shows up the listview with the text.
 But I get error when performing the below code like

> 05-23 14:21:47.350 4821-4821/? I/System.out: infoss route here105
>   infoss From here 1 05-23 14:21:47.350 4821-4821/? W/ResourceType: No
>   package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000069
>   05-23 14:21:47.350 4821-4821/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x41671c80)

**In system.out it prints the value but cannot execute when i bind it into holder!**  I used  [this link](https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/CustomListViewDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pcsalt/example/customlistviewdemo/MyBaseAdapter.java) as an help. Any help would be great! Sorry if I lack something in question! Thank you

```
System.out.println("infoss route here" +information.getRoute_no() +" infoss From here " +information.getFrom());
      myViewHolder.route.setText(information.getRoute_no());
        //myViewHolder.route.setText(infos.get(position).getRoute_no());
        myViewHolder.bus_from.setText(information.getFrom());
        //myViewHolder.bus_from.setText(infos.get(position).getFrom());
        myViewHolder.bus_to.setText(information.getTo());
        myViewHolder.v_type.setText(information.getV_type());
        myViewHolder.get_on.setText(information.getFrom());
        myViewHolder.get_off.setText(information.getChangeid1());
        myViewHolder.distance.setText(information.getDist3());
```

Comment: is `getRoute_no()` return `int`? then use `setText(String.valueOf(information.getRoute_no()))`

Comment: Damnn me!! WHat was i doing!! thanks a lot !! That was such a silly mistake! thanks again!